# Where & How to start?

Tags: xna, c#, .net, online, card-game

I want to start a new development of a Online 3D Card Game.

I have alot of expirience in C# .NET and Sockets and everything.

I started to play with XNA Game Studio, but i found it a mass.

No Visual Help like in any other Game Engine or like in Windows Forms.

My question is that, i dont know where and hwo to start on the XNA Game Studio, there are not alot of tutorials on the web, and if there are some they are very old.

So i thougt of moving to my favorite Workspace, a normal Windows Forms app with a server managed in a Console Application.

Should i stay with XNA? or go to Windows Form?

And if i go to Windows Forms, will i be able to use 3D objects there? and use some features from the XNA Framework by importing the librarys ?

--

Lets say my game will be 2D does Windows Forms support a game loop? Does it support Full Screen? Does it gives the option to fully redesign so it wont look like Windows Forms app?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the MS tutorials? http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

Comment: @Tetrad yes they actually very very basic and there is no community to support these kinde of gave development, Lets say my game will be 2D does Windows Forms support a game loop? Does it support Full Screen? Does it gives the option to fully redesign so it wont look like Windows Forms app?

Comment: Those questions are better than "where do I start" for the Q&A site format.

Comment: GDSE is better suited for the Q&A format; This question doesn't fit that standard.

Answer (score 7):

There are tons of books that you can find on Amazon to get you started. Just search 'XNA' on Amazon, and grab the first book that interests you. One title I highly recommend is XNA 4.0 Game Development by Example: Beginner's Guide by Kurt Jaegers. He'll walk you through several games step by step, the best way to learn, and most fun, in my opinion. You'll even be able to reuse the code in those examples in your own projects. This will only teach you 2D game development in XNA, however. If you want to do 3D, you'll need to graduate to other books and begin to study 3D math, another major topic that's an absolute must to understand before doing any type of 3D graphics programming.

I don't know what the design of your "Online 3D Card Game" is, so I don't know what you require. But if it needs to be in 3D, and more complex than images in a PictureBox object, I'd seriously do it in XNA. WinForms would not be the proper environment to fulfill your game design. If you decide to do completely 2D, then yes, WinForms can support a game loop, if you code one. At its core, a WinForm application is nothing more than an empty Window.